# Encode `~str` to base64 in Rust

Tags: base64, rust

I'd like to encode a `~str` to base64 in Rust, to implement HTTP Basic Authentication.

I found `extra::base64`, but I don't get how it's supposed to be used.  The `ToBase64` trait seems to have an implementation for `&[u8]`, but it's not found by the compiler.  The following test program:

```rust
extern mod extra;

fn main() {
    use extra::base64::MIME;

    let mut config = MIME;
    config.line_length = None;
    let foo = ::std::os::args()[0];
    print(foo.as_bytes().to_base64(config));
}
```

fails with the following error on Rust 0.9:

```
rustc -o test test.rs
test.rs:9:11: 9:44 error: type `&[u8]` does not implement any method in scope named `to_base64`
test.rs:9     print(foo.as_bytes().to_base64(config));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you have to add `use extra::base64;`

Comment: @Arjan, it won't work. Importing module does not automatically import its traits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The ToBase64 trait seems to have an implementation for &[u8], but it's
>   not found by the compiler.

Indeed, it is not found by the compiler in your code because you're not importing it. In order to use trait implementations, you have to import the trait itself:

```rust
extern mod extra;

fn main() {
    use extra::base64::{ToBase64, MIME};

    let mut config = MIME;
    config.line_length = None;
    let foo = ::std::os::args()[1];
    print(foo.as_bytes().to_base64(config));
}
```

(I've changed `args()[0]` to `args()[1]` since it is more interesting to encode command line arguments instead of executable name only :))

Comment: Note that a few days ago, `extra::base64` has been moved to `serialize::base64`. You will have to replace `extra` by `serialize` in your code.

Comment: @barjak As I said, I'm using rust 0.9.

Comment: sure but this info will be useful for future visitors of this site.